# Wall Drywall extending up between ceiling joists

Tags: drywall

I am renovating my basement. I have exposed floor joists as a ceiling. I am not drywalling the ceiling. However I want to extend my drywall panels on the walls up between the joists. Has anyone ever done this successfully? I added blocking between the joists aligned with the wall studs beneath. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "However I want to extend my drywall panels on the walls up between the joists." - Why? "Has anyone ever done this successfully?" - As opposed to failingly? "I added blocking between the joists aligned with the wall studs beneath." - So the sheetrock has an attachment point, nice.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Just to avoid cutting the drywall at the top? To cover one edge of the floor joist?

Comment: just paint the blocking.

Answer (score 2):

The walls that are parallel to the joists won't be a problem unless there are pipes going through the walls. Then you'll have to make a break in the drywall for the pipes. The walls that are perpendicular to the joists will have the same problem with pipes but the joists will will take some accurate measurements and careful cutting. I'd suggest cutting a 15 inch piece of drywall off the top or bottom of a scrap piece and holding it up against the joists and wall or edge of new drywall and mark the joist locations to it. Then, place the piece on your actual drywall piece and transfer the markings, like a template. Cut with a rotary tool or saber saw with a fine blade and then install the finished piece. Continue down the wall in the same fashion.